# Application with multiple language

Tags: android, fonts, textview, typeface

One of the my application feature is **set language(Arabic,French,German etc).**

As per android doc **i am successfully integrate and work like charm.**

But some of the text comes from server so how to convert those text to different languages.

If any one have idea then please share.

Comment: When you request the text from the server, pass the language - and get your server to send the response in the appropriate language.  This is how I do it in my app.

Comment: you could store different language strings on server and provide the matching by passing the current langugae `http://example.com?lang=de`

Comment: but in server have xml file with just english contain so how can i put in (ex arabic).

Comment: If your server contains only english language strings, then you cannot do anything.  You need to have multiple translations on the server to be able to provide appropriate versions.

Comment: @AleksG One more thing some of the data is editable so how can i manage?and is this possible?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "editable".  You start the same way - pass the language to the server, get the corresponding string back.  I'm not sure what you do with them after editing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass the current language code to the server request

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

And of course, the server has to be able to respond to it in the corresponding language